# Use linq to find if IPv6 is in range of a SQL record in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ipv6

Currently our system validates that users are from particular institutions. We use IPv4 addresses stored as bigint in SQL. An entity would submit their network's range of IP addresses (From and To). We store those address as a string and also as a bigint. Then when we check a user's connection by converting their IPv4 to a bigint and doing basically a between.

Data would be stored like this:

```
EntityID                                FromIP       FromIPint    ToIP            ToIPint 
8D32CFE4-3247-4BA7-9B51-94E8276B4B74    192.168.0.0  3232235520   192.168.0.254   3232235674
```

We query using linq like this:

```
var activeInstitutionEntities = (
    from ie in db.InstitutionEntities
    join ieip in db.InstitutionEntityIPs on ie.InstitutionEntityID equals ieip.InstitutionEntityID
    join i in db.Institutions on ie.InstitutionID equals i.InstitutionID
    where
        ieip.FromIPInteger <= ipAddressInteger &&
        ieip.ToIPInteger >= ipAddressInteger
    select ie.InstitutionEntityID).ToList();
```

So, an IPv4 of 192.168.0.54 would return a Guid, but 192.168.1.54 would not.

Now we would like to update the system to handle IPv6, checking to find the record the IP is in the range of as before. Our thoughts were to store the IP as a string as before, but the binary in a varbinary(16) field. However, linq cannot do a compare on binary values.

We were hoping to find a more elegant solution. What can we do to validate?

Comment: i see you needs to compare the last number in the IP string... so you have to split it: FromIP.Split('.')[3]... why stores the integer value?

Comment: Split('.') won't work on IPv6. It's not always the last set. It could be 192.168.12.0 to 192.168.15.254. Or it could be 2001:ac10:0db8:fe01:02d5:0000:0000:0000 to 2001:ac10:0db8:fe01:02d5:0000:0000:ffff.

Comment: Is it `LINQ to SQL` or `LINQ to Entities` or other?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you could require the addresses to be compliant with RFC 5952, giving you a consistent addressing scheme. Also, in IPv6, the network portion of the address will be the first 64 bits (4 words) of an address. Most companies will be assigned something like a /48, but it could be less than that (/32) for very large companies like ISPs. In any event, RFC 5952 was designed to create an IPv6 addressing standard for these sorts of situations.

Comment: This is LINQ to SQL.